# Is there a minimum requirement for Plasma Desktop?

Tags: arch-linux, plasma5, void-linux, kde-neon

I wanted to run Arch linux and Plasma Desktop on a 15 year old PC. It's Intel DG31PR, built in VGA, Intel Dual Core Processor and 4GB RAM. Arch gets installed and GNOME desktop works without any issue on that BUT Plasma Desktop isn't working! I left it for half an hour to see the sddm breeze login screen BUT it didn't show up!

Is there any way to make plasma desktop run on it?

---

**EDIT**

Kubuntu 18.04 live usb works on that system with both 1280x1024 and 1366x768 monitors! I'd choppy font issue on 1366x768 SyncMaster with Arch and Plasma Desktop 5.16.4 on another AMD Quad Core with ATI Radeon 3000 BUT on Kubuntu fonts are alright on this system on this resolution, it's using Plasma version 5.12.8. Here's a few information about the system from Kubuntu live usb:

[image]

How can I make Arch with Plasma 5.16.4 work on that system?

---

**EDIT**

It must be a problem specific to KDE neon and Arch, Void Linux works on this system with Plasma version 5.16.4:

[image]

BUT it's an issue with OpenGL:

[image]

and Animations (in Desktop Behavior) don't work even if I click `Re-enable OpenGL detection`! Here's the information related to graphics:

[image]

Can this OpenGL issue be fixed on void?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for KDE?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359051/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-kde)

Comment: Related on Ask Ubuntu: [This community wiki answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/333864) has the minimum and recommended requirements for Kubuntu for LTS releases. Both are unofficial, but probably the most practical information to this date.

Comment: @clearkimura, none of those answer this problem!

Answer (score 1):

[The minimum system requirements for KDE neon](https://community.kde.org/Neon/UserEdition/5.6#Minimum_Requirements)

> Installing KDE neon requires:
>
> - 64-bit PC (Intel or AMD)
> - 2GB memory
> - 10GB disk space

[The minimum system requirements for Kubuntu (Ubuntu + KDE 4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu#System_requirements)

> - Processor   2 GHz dual core (x86)
> - Memory  2 GB
> - Hard drive capacity 25 GB
> - Video card  VGA @ 1024×768

Sure, that is not exactly what you're looking for, but I bet this should give you an idea. Your PC should satisfy Plasma. There might be some other issues that you have to address.

**UPD:** 64bit CPU **is not a requirement** for KDE Plasma, it will work fine on 32bit CPU as well. These minimum requirements listed for Kubuntu and Neon are higher than KDE actually needs.

Comment: I'd 64 bit windows 7 on it, it used to work on a 1366x768 Syncmaster monitor! I'd tried KDE Neon live usb stick, it didn't work, either!

Comment: @EmonHaque does it work with Kubuntu live usb?

Comment: I've never tried kubuntu before BUT kubuntu 18.04 live usb actually works on both 1280x1024 and 1366x768 monitors! Why don't KDE neon 5.16.4 and Plasma desktop 5.16.4 on Arch work on any of those monitors?